# window.parent.location.reload(true); causing problems!

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a aspx page that pops up a new window to edit some info.  When the user is done editing they click save and at the end of the save event I have this C# code:

```
Context.Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>window.parent.location.reload(true);window.frameElement.commitPopup();</script>");
Context.Response.Flush();
Context.Response.End();
```

So that the parent page will refresh and display the updated info.  My problem is that if I have done some other action on the previous page that caused a postback, the code above will try to redo that postback  (attempting to delete an item for instance).

Is there some way that I can update my information on the parent page without redoing the last postback?

Comment: There is an event that fires when the popup closes on the parent page. You can handle that and perhaps refresh just the section that needs refreshing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just load the same page with a random parametre, to force the load, but not make reload that make and post back

```
window.parent.location.href = window.parent.location.href + '?rnd=' + Math.random();
```

Now if your href have all ready other parametres, you can add **&rnd**.

If you make many reloads you can replace the rnd like this:

```
window.parent.location.href = window.parent.location.href.replace(/\?rnd.*$/, '?rnd' + Math.random());
```

Also you can do

```
window.parent.location.replace(window.parent.location.href.replace(/\?rnd.*$/, '?rnd' + Math.random()));
```